# Lua: Can I have a comma after a function that returns a table?

Tags: function, lua, lua-table

So my Lua code looks something like this:

```
function makeTable()
    return {1,2,3}
end

table = {
    makeTable(),
    {4,5,6}
}
```

The result of `table` should be `{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}`.

I'm concerned about the comma after `makeTable()`. Is this valid in Lua for a function that returns a table, or is there a better way of having a function returning a table be the first item of a table?

Answer (score 1):

That works. Is there any issue with your code or something you are trying to achieve precisely? Or if you wish, you can do:

```
function makeTable()
    return {{1,2,3}}
end

t = maketable()
table.insert(t, {4,5,6})
```

Comment: I was asking as I'm not too familiar with Lua (having a comma after a function seems weird), and that I'm modding Factorio (uses Lua for its mod API) and need to create a lot of related items and recipes.

Comment: You can do very evil things with LUA, it's a little bit like Javascript, you can abuse the crap out of your code and make it work through weird antics.

If you have multiple items to create with the same pattern, you can add parameters too, such as:
`function makeTable(additionalpart) { return {{1,2,3},additionalpart} end`
and then call it as:
`t = makeTable({4,5,6})`

May I also recommend you use the `local` prefix to your variables when they shouldn't be exposed elsewhere. Finally, `table` is used for table functions, that's a part of my previous edit. Use something else :)

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly valid `Lua`. Try adding this to the bottom of the code:

```
io.write("{")
for i,v in ipairs(table) do 
    io.write("{")
    for j,m in ipairs(v) do
       io.write(m)
       io.write(",") 
    end
    io.write("},") 
end
print("}")
```

you will see it prints: `{{1,2,3,},{4,5,6,},}`.

You are correctly adding a an array to your 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.But i suppose this will be cleaner:

```
function makeTable()
    return {1,2,3}
end

local t = {}
table.insert(t, makeTable())
table.insert(t, {4, 5, 6})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% fine.

You write that "having a comma after a function seems weird". Well, that comma is doing exactly the same thing that commas in table expressions always do: it's separating one table value from the next table value.

In other words, `{ makeTable(), {4,5,6} }` is exactly the same as `{1,2}`, except that it has `makeTable()` in place of `1`, and `{4,5,6}` in place of `2`.